# add step to OPC without overriding: update section

Tags: magento, layout, checkout, observers

so this is a follow up question of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607492/add-step-to-opc-without-overriding).
I am adding a step before the shipping-methods by observer. I have a problem for getting the html used to update the step's tab content. Despite my best efforts it still loads the html of the shipping-method step instead of the html I want.
This is the code of the observer:

```
public function gotoViesStep($observer)
{
    $response = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getResponse();
    $body = $response->getBody();
    $result = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($body);

    if (in_array('error', $result)) {
        return;
    }

    //if conditions are met, go to vies check
    if ($result['goto_section'] == 'shipping_method') {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $countryId = $shippingAddress->getCountryId();

        if (($countryId != 'BE') && ($this->_countryInEU($countryId))) {
            $result['goto_section'] = 'vies';
            $result['allow_sections'][] = 'vies';
            $result['country_id'] = $countryId;

            $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'vies',
                    'html' => $this->_getViesHtml()
                );

            $response->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
}

protected function _getViesHtml()
{
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $update->load('checkout_onepage_vies');
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput();
    return $output;
}
```

and the layout.xml of that handle `checkout_onepage_vies`:

```
<checkout_onepage_vies>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="correctionvat/onepage_vies" name="root" output="toHtml" template="correctionvat/onepage/vies.phtml"/>
</checkout_onepage_vies>
```

If I put something directly instead of trying to load the block, it works. I.E., if, instead of `'html' => $this->_getViesHtml()` I do `'html' => 'foobar'`, the content of the step is `foobar`.

So it's like as the output/layout/blocks is already charged by the OnepageController my attempt to re-charge it again fails.
Any thaughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to the list of added layout handles. You need to reset them before calling `load()` method. Also you need to reset updates array, that contain previously parsed xml by calling `resetUpdates()` method.

You `getViesHtml()` should look like the following in the end:

```
protected function _getViesHtml()
{
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

    $layout->getUpdate()
         ->resetHandles()
         ->resetUpdates()
         ->load('checkout_onepage_vies');

    $layout->generateXml()
         ->generateBlocks();

    $output = $layout->getOutput();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: thanx Ivan, once again :-) I tried that but it didn't worked. I've just tried it on a clean install and it works: something else is in the way then, I'll have to dig in the custom modules.